# Open-faas function will not deploy

Tags: openfaas

I am attempting to deploy an open-faas function from the cli. The command I am using is below.

> sudo /usr/local/bin/faas-cli deploy -f my-template.yml

This gives an error of

> Is OpenFaaS deployed? Do you need to specify the --gateway flag?
> Put http://127.0.0.1:8080/system/functions: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8080: connect: connection refused

> Function 'my-template' failed to deploy with status code: 500

I am thinking the Open-faas service might not be running, but I can't figure out how to turn it on. Can anyone provide some insight?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

you can use `kubectl get service -n openfaas`, get gateway-external service IP. and then `sudo /usr/local/bin/faas-cli deploy -f my-template.yml --gateway=http://IP:8080`

Answer (score 0):

You have to install OpenFaas, which I did following the "Get OpenFaaS" part of this guide: https://www.openfaas.com/blog/get-started-with-java-openjdk11/
After installing it, it will print out the command which you need in order to forward the gateway and log yourself in.